# How can I prevent the Review task queue clearing after switching to 'Stats' or 'History' tab?

Tags: bug, review, review-stats

I thought I'd ask this here to see if anyone else is experiencing this.

When I am conducting reviews, if I switch over to the 'Stats' or 'History' tabs and then back to the review tasks tab, it always says that I have no new reviews, even when I left a review there before. I'm pretty sure that there *are* still reviews pending, but I'm not offered them. This happens without fail, but resets each day.

If I refresh the page, the problem persists, but if I reopen in a new tab, I am given a new review task

As I generally only use Stack Overflow, I've only encountered this on that site.

Is anyone else able to reproduce this?

Found using Macbook Pro (M1) 2020, Big Sur 11.6.2 (20G314), Chrome Version 98.0.4758.80 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: Switching away and then back again just displays the item I was previously shown both on Stack Overflow and here on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I get it too over on LawSE when I navigate away to any page (i.e. not just to Stats and History). I've not timed it but the queues seem to refresh and get re-populated after about 20 minutes or so. Opening a tab doesn't bring them back (Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having upgraded to Monterey 12.2.1 the issue seems to have been fixed. Chrome is now also on Version 98.0.4758.102, but I am unsure which of these (if either) resolved the issue.